# C program only writing ? to new file

Tags: c

I have this program:

```
int countLineTotal(FILE *file) {
    int line = 1;
    int ch = 'a';

    while (ch != EOF) {
        ch = fgetc(file);
        if (ch == '\n') {
            line++;
        }
    }
    return line;
}

void removeLine(char *name_of_file, int delete_line) {

    FILE *source_file;
    FILE *temporary_file;
    int temp = 1;
    int ch = 'a';

    source_file = fopen(name_of_file, "r");
    if (source_file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not open file: "); 
        return 1;
    }

    int line_total = countLineTotal(source_file);
    /*
        verify entered line number is valid
    */

    temporary_file = fopen("remove.temp", "w");
    if (temporary_file == NULL)
    { 
        perror("Could not open 'remove.temp': "); 
        return 1;
    }

    while (ch != EOF) {
        ch = fgetc(source_file);
        if (temp != delete_line) {
            putc(ch, temporary_file);
        }
        if (ch == '\n') {
            temp++;
        }
    }

    fclose(source_file);
    fclose(temporary_file);
    remove(name_of_file);
    rename("remove.temp", name_of_file);
}

int main() {
    int line_num = 3;
    char *file_name = "myfile.txt";

    removeLine(file_name, line_num);
    return 0;
}
```

Contents of `myfile.txt`:

```
content on line1
content on line2
content on line3
content on line4
content on line5
```

Final output in `myfile.txt`:

```
?
```

The program is either not writing anything to the temporary file, or it's completely overwriting it with... nothing? When trying to debug, I noticed that the `while (ch != EOF)` exited when `temp` was `1` and never higher. Not sure why this is at all.

Edit: updated code.
After adding the code I missed out, I realized that I forgot to set the pointer back to the beginning of the file... which explains why temp was never higher than 1.

Comment: `while (ch != EOF) ` causes undefined behaviour as `ch` was never initialized. You need to read the character and then check if it is EOF (not the other way around)

Comment: Use the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to compile your program. Improve it to get no warnings. Then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program. Read documentation related to the [C functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) you are using; you may want to use [fflush(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)

Comment: @M.M I initialized it with a value, yet I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: You have no error checking on your calls to `fopen`.

Comment: @PaulR In the original program, I do. I didn't think they were too important here so I left them out. I'll update the post.

Comment: You still read and write ch in the wrong order. Think what happens after `EOF` is read

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and include that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had forgot to set the pointer back to the beginning of the file, so the program started reading from the end of the file. This explains why `temp` was never higher than 1.

Answer (score 1):

the code below works. Check out the differences, with tool like tkdiff. I changed a few things like e.g. file_name[12] and while-loop to do{}while(); , because you can NOT check "ch" BEFORE you have read any value to "ch". The code works now ...

COMMENT: the "remove" and "rename" is really dangerous in this program. If you call program twice, then you have removed line 3 and 4, compared to original file. Rather work on a copy, or create a backup first... anyway that is not your question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void removeLine(char *name_of_file, int delete_line) {

    FILE *source_file;
    FILE *temporary_file;
    int temp = 1;
    char ch;
    
    source_file = fopen(name_of_file, "r");
    if (source_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file: "); 
        return;
    }

    temporary_file = fopen("remove.temp", "w");
    if (temporary_file == NULL)
    { 
        printf("Could not open 'remove.temp': "); 
        return;
    }

    do{
        ch = fgetc(source_file);
        if (temp != delete_line) {
            fputc(ch, temporary_file);
        }
        if (ch == '\n') {
            temp++;
        }
    }while(ch != EOF);

    fclose(source_file);
    fclose(temporary_file);
    remove(name_of_file); // NOT GOOD
    rename("remove.temp", name_of_file); // NOT GOOD

}

int main() {
    int line_num = 3;
    char file_name[12] = "myfile.txt";

    removeLine(file_name, line_num);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, see the "dangerous" effect of calling the program several times:

```
$ cat myfile.txt
test1
test12 aa
test14 xx xx
test15  cc
test16
test17
test18
$ ./a.out
$ cat myfile.txt
test1
test12 aa
test15  cc
test16
test17
test18
$ ./a.out
$ cat myfile.txt
test1
test12 aa
test16
test17
test18
```